# One page website navbar to highlight when on section (using bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and smoothscroll for my one page website. I am unsure how to get the section in the navbar to become active though if someone scrolls to it - any help on this? I know how to get it to highlight when clicked but not sure about position

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <!-- nav bar -->
      <div class="navbar-brand"><b>Merisa Lee</b></div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="height: 1px;">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#work" class="smoothScroll">Work</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="resume.pdf">Resume</a></li>    
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are a few plugins called Smooth Scroll and both on GitHub have instructions.

Comment: Did you try the bootstrap included `Scrollspy` functionality? It should do the trick for you.. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: Thanks Sebsemillia! I used scrollspy and it worked :)